# UIImageView strange stretch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've made an app, where you can take pictures. It'll be shown in the view afterwards. I would like to show the whole photo, without cutting anything or stretching anything.

```
bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.bgImage];
bg.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:bg];
```

.. later on ..

```
bg.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[bg addGestureRecognizer:tap];
bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
bg.clipsToBounds = YES;
bg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The image now looks like this:

[image]

I simply can't understand this, when the content mode is set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to make the frame of the imageView to fit the screen it's displayed on:

```
bg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
```

(or using screenBounds)

You could make the background black or white or something. Then that should work.

Hope that helps :)